# How to call a javascript function in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to store form details and display a popup box, when I click the submit button. For this I use `try { } finally { }` but how to link popup box function in JavaScript to the C# file?

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function xpopup() {
    document.getElementById("x").onclick = function () 
    {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("xPopup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

C#:

```
try { }
finally
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "<script>function xpopup();</script>", false);
}
```

Comment: Remove script and function, you don't need put keyword there. ScriptManager handle them automatically

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<script>` tag and `function` keyword as the `function` is already been defined:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "xpopup();", false);
```